# android and alarmManager

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I write application which will use alarm manager. First I set up alarm manager to run some service every 20sec. Then service start some Thread. Here code of my service:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ExtendedLog.i(TAG, "On start command");

    Thread t = new Thread(wat);
            t.start;

    this.stopSelf();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

My problme is that this running properly only for few minutes. After that alarm manager starts service but thread does not start. I really dont know where is problem. Do anyone of you know what may be wrong with it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Anything in your logcat?

Comment: No, the strangest thing is that there isnothing special in logcat. Just form some moment Threads stop starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you stopping the service if you want the thread to keep running?

Looking in the [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) documentation:

> All cleanup (stopping threads, unregistering receivers) should be complete upon returning from onDestroy().

So since you did not stop your threads in `onDestroy` as requested , the system probably interrupts and stops them on its own.

What are you trying to do here? Starting a new thread & new service each 20 seconds is probably (I might even say *obviously*) not the best way to implement whatever you need to do... What is the code the runnable `wat` runs?

Comment: Wat just do couple line of code (there is no loop) and thats all, so it exist only for this couple lines.

Comment: It do some needed work eg. generate some data, write data to database, or communicate with server